# Использование reset.css

Tags: css

Как-то не могу понять почему подчеркиваются атрибуты и как это пофиксить
p.s обнуление стилей работает но эти ошибки смущают как-то
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это не ошибки, а предупреждение. Не указано дефолтное значение, а только под движки. Нужно добавить ещё `appearance: none`

Comment: Установите расширение `error lens`, очень полезное.

Comment: спасибо большое !